# Terminal Linux - referencing executable file - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, file, command-line, terminal, directory

I'm not great in the terminal, and I can't figure out why its returning this. It's probably really obvious so apologies for asking, but the executable file I'm referencing is definitely in that file path, and after researching I can't seem to find an answer:

```
/home/user/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc object_detection/protos /*.proto --python_out=.

object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory
```

(I can't cd into it as I need to do this in a particular directory)

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I figured it out in case anyone runs into the same issue: It doesn't like the "/home/user" so I completely got rid of that - this is a tutorial I found stepping me through some issues https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1834

Answer (score 0):

It seems bash is looking for a specific file that has the name "[star]" instead of using this as a wildcard.

I think you might need to use a pipe to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

From your command line, it looks like `protoc` is the executable, located at `/home/user/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc`. And that you're giving it *two* arguments separated by a space: `object_detection/protos` and `/*.proto`. If you have spaces in the file path, you'll need to escape them or double-quote them:

`protoc object_detection/protos\ /*.proto` or
`protoc "object_detection/protos /*.proto"`

The odd thing is that the error message indicates differently:

`object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory`

Or possibly the `protoc` executable needs the absolute (complete) path for file arguments. If from your current working directory the command `ls object_detection/protos/*.proto` shows results for you, then you can try running your command like this to use absolute file paths:

`/home/user/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc $PWD/object_detection/protos/*.proto`

`$PWD` is an environment variable that contains your working directory path.